# Get an Enumeration (for the Keys) of a Map (HashMap) in Java?

Tags: java, enumeration

As far as I understand this, it seems that there is not a direct way of getting an `Enumeration` directly for the Keys of a `HashMap`. I can only get a `keySet()`. From that `Set`, I can get an `Iterator` but an `Iterator` seems to be something different than an `Enumeration`.

What is the best and most performant way to directly get an `Enumeration` from the Keys of a `HashMap`?

Background: I am implementing my own [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getKeys) (=>`getKeys()` Method), and I have to provide/implement a method that returns the Enumeration of all Keys. But my implementation is based on a `HashMap` so I need to somehow figure out how to best convert betweens these two "Iterator/Enumerator" techniques.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need Enumerations instead of Iterators? Enumeration's Javadoc recommends that you use Iterator instead.

Comment: well, the Class I am implementing requires an Enumeration:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getKeys() (see the getKey() Method there)
The only thing what I could do is to implement it completely different and not use HashMap at all. Nevertheless I would be very much interested in learning whats the best and most performant way of getting an Enumeration for the Keys of a Map. thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Apache commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) have an adapter that makes the `Iterator` available for use like an `Enumeration`. Take a look at [IteratorEnumeration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/IteratorEnumeration.html).

> Adapter to make an Iterator instance appear to be an Enumeration instances

So in short you do the following:

```
Enumeration enumeration = new IteratorEnumeration(hashMap.keySet().iterator());
```

Alternatively, if you (for some reason) don't want to include commons-collections, you can implement this adapter yourself. It is easy - just make an implementation of `Enumeration`, pass the `Iterator` in a constructor, and whenever `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()` are called, you call the `hasNext()` and `next()` on the underlying `Iterator`.

Use this if you are forced to use `Enumeration` by some API contract (as I assume the case is). Otherwise use `Iterator` - it is the recommended option.

Comment: Google Collections also supports this using `Iterators.asEnumerator()`: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#asEnumeration(java.util.Iterator)

Comment: hello Bozho. Thanks, especially interesting was your comment how to implement this on my own. I did not realize so far that I could do this on my own.

Answer (score 48):

I think you can use the method *enumeration* from **java.util.Collections** class to achieve what you want.

The API doc of the method enumerate has this to say:

***public static  Enumeration enumeration(Collection c)**

Returns an enumeration over the specified collection. This provides interoperability with legacy APIs that require an enumeration as input.*

For example, the below code snippet gets an instance of Enumeration from the keyset of HashMap

```
 final Map <String,Integer> test = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
 test.put("one",1);
 test.put("two",2);
 test.put("three",3);
 final Enumeration<String> strEnum = Collections.enumeration(test.keySet());
 while(strEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
     System.out.println(strEnum.nextElement());
 }
```

**and resulting the output is:**
one
two
three

Comment: +1 This is the way to go to as long as you start with the collection. No need to write your own adapter to enumerate a key set.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a adapter to adapt to Enumeration.

```
    public class MyEnumeration implements Enumeration {

        private Iterator iterator;

        public MyEnumeration(Iterator iterator){
            this.iterator = iterator;
        }


        public MyEnumeration(Map map) {
            iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }


        @Override
        public Object nextElement() {
            return iterator.next();
        }

    }
```

And then you can use this custom enumeration :)