# How to use a map with a generic enum type as function return type in Java

Tags: java, templates, generics, dictionary, enums

I am using an interface method that returns the map with these key, values.

```
public interface IParse<T> {

    Map<String, T> parse(); //T is an enum type
}
```

Now in the implementation classes, I use the function parse with

```
public class TestClass1 implements IParse
{

    public Map<String, EnumType1> parse()
    {
         Map<String, EnumType1> map1 = new HashMap<>();
         // Logic to fill the map
         return map1;
    }
}

public class TestClass2 implements IParse
{

    public Map<String, EnumType2> parse()
    {
         Map<String, EnumType2> map2 = new HashMap<>();
         // Logic to fill the map
         return map2;
    }
}
```

and return the map containing appropriate enum type. But eclipse seems does not like it. One of the help options shows "Infer Generic Type Arguments".

Now in the above case, how do I use properly return the map without any type casting. Is there any other way I can use the interface method with a return value a map containing values as enum class types. Please give me an example on how to do this.

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048131/get-an-enumeration-for-the-keys-of-a-map-hashmap-in-java

Comment: Please show us your actual code. Presumably your implementation classes must implement that interface, for example?